# Term for pcb test fixture that can access both sides of the board

Tags: production-testing

What is a good term for a pcb test fixture setup having, say, pogo pins that can reach lands on both sides of a device?
Could it be dual-side or double-sided?

Answer (score 1):

"iron maiden": it's like a bed of nails from both sides